# Returning properties from dbpedia Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

When I look at the HTML page: http://dbpedia.org/page/Bill_Nye I can see a lot of properties that are not returned in the following simple query from the Virtuoso page (http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql):

```
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?s ?p  WHERE {
 ?e foaf:name "Bill Nye"@en .
 ?e ?s ?p.
}
```

No results return when I try to access one of the properties I can see on this page- say foaf:depiction:

```
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT $depiction WHERE { 
?s foaf:name "Bill Nye"@en. 
?e foaf:depiction ?depiction 
}
```

When I run them via the sparql endpoint at http://dbpedia.org/sparql, after encoding

```
SELECT ?s ?p WHERE { ?e foaf:name "Bill Nye"@en.?e ?s ?p. }
```

I get

```
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=SELECT%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fe%20foaf%3Aname%20%22Bill%20Nye%22@en.%3Fe%20%3Fs%20%3Fp.%20%7D&format=json
```

And a result of what looks like all the properties shown at http://dbpedia.org/page/Bill_Nye.  I would love an explaniation of the difference, is it simply the Virtuoso interface or something more?  I'm pretty fresh at this semantic web, so please be gentle.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that you are sending the queries to two different Virtuoso installations:

- pt.dbpedia.org/sparql : is the international chapter for Portuguese language (PT stands for DBpedia Portuguese)
- dbpedia.org/sparql : is the main SPARQL endpoint for DBpedia, containing data from multiple languages, but in an English-centric way.

You will also have different experiences with es.dbpedia.org, it.dbpedia.org, el.dbpedia.org, etc.

I18n chapters do not load exactly the same data sets as the main DBpedia. Please see:
http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/DBpedia_datasets

Answer (score -1):

I believe the following query (ordered) will enable you to more easily identify the missing results --

```
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?s ?p ?o  WHERE
{
 ?s foaf:name "Bill Nye"@en .
 ?s ?p ?o.
}
order by 2
```

here you can easily identify that all the missing results have predicates of the form -

```
is ********** of
```

Basically, these are just eye candy in the human viewable Html view - and represent additional relationships wherever the object of some other subject is http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bill_Nye

That is -

```
<something else> ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bill_Nye>
```

Comment: If it is just eye candy, why does the same query sent to dbpedia.org/sparql work?  Running "SELECT ?s ?p WHERE { ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bill_Nye>. }" does not show results you suggest.

Comment: Your query returns the same results as mine.